# Send props to an array of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of components that I want to render, but I don't know how to send props to each of them. Do you have any idea how? I am using also using formik for form management and the page components consist of basic inputs.

```
const pages = [<Page1 />, <Page2 />, <Page3 />, <Page4 />]
```

and I am rendering them this way:

```
<div>{pages[state]}</div>
```

Comment: just pass the props in the array declaration? es `const pages = [<Page1 prop={"yo"} />, ....]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options to achieve this:

**Option 1: On the declaration site you may pass the state** while initialising the array.

```
const pages = [<Page1 props={page1Prop: 'value'}/>, 
               <Page2 props=page2Props />, 
               <Page3 props=page3Props />, 
               <Page4 props=page4Props />]
```

Or if you do not want or can not update the declaration you may pass when rendering:
Or you can

**Option 2: clone the component prop and apply the new props**

```
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {React.cloneElement(pages[currentPage] propsForPage[currentPage])}
        OR
        {React.cloneElement(pages[currentPage] {someProp:'value'})}
      </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using `React.cloneElement`:

```
const newProps = {}

<div>{React.cloneElement(pages[state], newProps)}</div>
```

[React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)

Answer (score -1):

Could you not initialise the component in the array?

```
const pages = [Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4]

return (
  <div>
    {pages.map(page => {
      const Component = <page />

      return (
        <Component {...props} />
      )
     }
  </div>
)
```